# Calling methods in child view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have an app written in Swift for iOS 13 where I present a view modally using storyboards. Once the new view is being presented, I want the parent to call a method which is located inside the child view controller (of my custom class which inherits from `UIViewController`).

To do this, I plan to have a method inside my parent view controller that gets the modal view controller being presented as its child. Once I get this reference, I will call the child's function from my parent view controller.

I realise this is probably a bad design decision, but I haven't found a way to avoid this approach. I have looked all over stackoverflow to find an answer, but I haven't found any yet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you not instantiate the child view controller, set one of it’s properties (maybe a Bool flag) then present it, and use the property in the child view’s `viewDidLoad()` method?

Comment: Thanks @Chris, that's an approach I hadn't thought of as a new iOS dev, and it is a much better design choice than mine. If you would post this as a full answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll post an answer when I’m at my computer. Are you using segues or instantiate no storyboard view controllers in code? Either is fine.

Comment: Using segues – I find it easier that way.

Comment: I’ve posted my answer without segues - need to remind myself how to use them. Basically it’s calling `performSegue()` and doing setup on an overridden `prepareFor(segue:)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate the child view controller and set its properties before presenting it. Then the code that changes the child view controller based on the data is put in the `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    func goToChildViewController(object: CustomObject) {
        guard let childViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "child") as? ChildViewController else { fatalError("Cannot instantiate child view controller!") }
        childViewController.myProperty = true
        childViewController.myObject = myObject // Example of how to pass data from a data model
        self.present(childViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    var myProperty = false
    var myObject: CustomObject? = nil

    override viewDidLoad() {
        if myProperty {
            // Conditional code here
        }
    {
}
```

Alternatively, you could trigger a segue in code instead of presenting the child view controller directly.

In this case, you would set up the child view controller inside the parent view controller’s overridden `prepare(for:sender:)` method, where the child view controller can be accessed using `segue.destinationViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

**Through Segue**

When segue triggered maybe through a button press or a table view selection `prepare(for:)` method will be called on your view controller, at this point you can configure your `DestinationViewController` by setting some properties.

```
RootViewController.Swift
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldFirstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelFullname: UILabel!
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let firstVC = segue.destination as? FirstViewController else { return }
    firstVC.firstname = textFieldFirstName.text

}
```

After typing the `firstname` and tap enter button , `firstname` value is passed to `firstViewController` and assigned to related UILabel in `viewDidLoad()` Method.

```
FirstViewController.Swift
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldLastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var labelFirstName: UILabel!

var firstname: String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
labelFirstName.text = “Firstname: \(firstname ?? “”)”
}
```

> You can achieve same thing through closure and Delegates